# Animate expand of group in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

i've trying to find a best solution to animate expanding of group in my ExpandableListView but didn't find any universal solution.
is there the right decision for the ExpandableListView, or i need to use a simple ListView?